# How to check the distance between a specific element an index? Python3

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

```
A = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
B = 9
```

I want to find out the distances between the index[9] (B) and each of it's closest's 1's. For example, If we look at list A, we see that index 9 is this:

```
A = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
                                ^
```

I would like to figure out the distances between B(index 9) and it's nearest 1's. For example, the nearest 1's in this case would be this:

```
A = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, B, 0, 0, 1, 0]
                          ^              ^
```

So in this case the output would be:

```
>> [2, 3] ##Since the distance between 1, 0, B is 2 and the distance between B, 0, 0, 1 is 3.
```

So far I've come up with the following code:

```
def checkDistance(A, B):
     for i in A:
         if i == 1:
            #Check if it is the closest to B
            #Check distance
```

Sadly I'm a beginner in python and I am struggling to finish. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 def distance(lst,index):
         c=[i for i,j in enumerate(lst) if j==1]
         for k,l in zip(c[:-1],c[1:]):
              if k < index < l:
                  return [index-k, l-index]

a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, B, 0, 0, 1, 0]
b = 9
distance(a, b)
Out: [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function. In this case, to make the function more abstract, you needn't force the value for the comparison to be 1 in the function.

In the function below, you do a for loop starting at the position you specified (in Python indexes start at 0, not at 1) and finishing when the list finishes.
The if statement compares `element` with the value of the list at a given position `i`

```
def checkDistance(lst,index,element):
    counter = 0
    results = []
    for i in range(index,len(lst)):
        if lst[i] == element:
            print("Detected element at distance: " + str(counter))
            results.append(counter)
        counter += 1

    return results
```